# Have all threads of a thread pool execute a given function

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I use a slightly customed version of progschj thread pool implementation (https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool). It works well so far for my use cases, except the one described hereafter.

I would like to be able to have each thread of the pool to execute once a given function, in order for example to have each thread set some thread local variables.

```cpp
thread_pool.execute_all([] () { do some stuff; });
```

This call should be blocking and wait until all the threads of the pool have executed the function.

I have tried to modify the main loop of the threads to achieve this, but I can't manage to ensure that each thread of the pool executes the given function exactly once and the main thread waits until they are done.

Could anyone propose a working version of this feature, or give a hint about how to achieve this?

Comment: It doesn't look like `thread_pool` has such a function. Are asking us how to add it? If so, what you are asking is for us to modify a library for you. It would make your question off topic for this site.

Comment: Yes, I actually try to add this feature to the thread pool, but can't manage to get a working solution.. I hoped that someone could think it is an interesting problem and could at least give some hints on how to make it (with this library or with any other thread pool implementation).

Comment: It's seems like you have to play a little with the `join` method of the threads.

Comment: Isn't `join` waiting for the thread to stop ? I do not want to stop the threads, only wait for them to have each executed the given function. Then they should continue to be available for new tasks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what problem are you trying to solve? Writing code that cares about the identities of thread-pool workers seems kind of suspicious. The `thread_pool` implementation that you are using now is trivial, but if you ever switch to a more sophisticated implementation, then you will need to be aware that it's common practice for thread pools to kill off workers when demand is low, and create new workers when demand becomes high.

Comment: I try to aggregate in parallel some information on data (for example: count odd elements on a big array of integers, each thread handling a part of the elements). I first create an array whose size is equal to the number of threads, so that each thread sums up its count in its own place. At the end, I sum up the sums to get the result. It works fine except that it falls right into the "false sharing" pattern because the array fits into a single cache line.. My current attempt is to have each thread compute its own result in a thread local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a counting semaphore barrier.

```
struct counting_barrier {
  explicit counting_barrier( std::ptrdiff_t c ):count(c) {}
  void operator--(int)& {
    this->operator--();
  }
  void operator--()& {
    auto l = lock();
    --count;
    cv.wait( l, [&]{
      return count<=0;
    } );
    cv.notify_all();
  }
private:
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock()& {
    return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
  }
  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::mutex m;
  std::ptrdiff_t count = 0;
};
```

now we can implement it using existing primitives.

```
template<class F>
void execute_all( F&& f ) {
  counting_barrier barrier(workers.size()+1);
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < workers.size(); ++i) {
    enqueue([&]{
      f();
      --barrier;
    });
  }
  --barrier;
}
```

and that should do it.  No worker is allowed past the barrier until `workers.size()` hit it; when the last worker is releasing the barrier, `workers.size()-1` **must** be blocked on it.  Thus every worker calls `f()` before the function returns.

Code untested.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine with 2 modifications : `wait_for` should be `wait` in `counting_barrier::operator--`. And as I want the execute_all function to wait for the threads to have all called the function, I store the `future`s returned by `enqueue` and wait for them.

Comment: @PierreKraemer When the barrier is decremented to 0, all the `f()`s have been called.  Waiting on the futures is redundant.  Oh wait, you are right, add one to the barrier; there, now `execute_all` also blocks on the barrier.  No need for two kinds of synchronization!

Comment: Yep. With the `workers.size()+1` count initialization and the last `--barrier` in the main function, it's ok :-)